# ¿Cómo mostrar una matriz en python?

Tags: python, matriz

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
import random
matriz=[]
filas=3;columnas=3
def elementos():
    for inicializar in range(filas):
        matriz.append([0]*columnas)

    for i in range(filas):
        for j in range(columnas):
            matriz[i][j]=random.randint(1,200)

def Mostrar():
    print("La matriz es la siguiente:")
    for i in matriz:
        print(i)

elementos()
mayor=max(item[2] for item in matriz)
print("El valor mas alto generado es el",mayor)
menor=min(item[2] for item in matriz)
print("El valor mas bajo generado es el",menor)
Mostrar()
```

Al mostrar la matriz el programa de esta mostrando la matriz con la forma 3x3 pero mostrando ademas los corchetes en cada fila y "," entre cada elemento en las filas, no encontré una solución y y no voy a usar alguna función de la libreria numpy, mi objetivo es que el programa de muestre la matriz de esta forma:

```
3  4  5
6  7  8
9  1  2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es imprimir de a un elemento a la vez, no toda la fila:

```
def Mostrar():
    print("La matriz es la siguiente:")
    for fila in matriz:
        for valor in fila:
            print("\t", valor, end=" ")
        print()
```

Use `"\t"` alinear rápidamente los valores en columna. Si quieres valores alineados por la derecha y todas las columnas de igual ancho, eso ya es tema de otra pregunta.

Puse `end=" "` para que el `print` no cambie de linea luego de imprimir un valor.

Cuando haz impreso toda una linea, pones un `print()` para forzar una nueva línea.

Produce:

```
La matriz es la siguiente:
     121     116     193 
     95      163     73 
     173     166     71
```

Comment: Otra forma sencilla, y más segura, de tabular los datos `print(f"{valor:<4}", end=" ")` (Python 3.6+). `<`, `^`, `>` alinean a la izquierda, centrado o derecha y 4 es el `relleno` de espacios, si no especificas otro caracter.

Comment: @aeportugal. Mejor agrega una respuesta explicando en detalle las opciones de formato disponibles. Asi la información será más visible, más clara y útil. También explica las diferencia entre 3.6 y 3.8 (f-string y esas cosas). Gracias por el aporte.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con un método de itertools, modifique el código pero es lo necesitas.

```
import itertools

randomNumber = [
  [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2]
]

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
  args = [iter(iterable)] * n
  return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

for matrix in randomNumber:
  for chunk in grouper(matrix, 3):
    print(" ".join(map(str, chunk)))
  print()

print("El valor mas alto es: %s"% max(randomNumber[0]))
print("El valor mas bajo es: %s"% min(randomNumber[0]))
```

Observé que cuando querías obtener el mínimo y máximo en tu lista estaba mal. Si quieres usar ramdom() solo debes reemplazar lo que contiene randomNumber, también coloque la lista tal y como sugieres el resultado que necesitas. Saludos